# Merging problem when calling same function twice with different parameters in C

Tags: c

i have this piece of code:

```
void Win_Check(int mat[][MAX], int player, int x1, int y1) {
    int check, check2, check3, check4, check5, check6;
    check = HorizontalCheck(x1, y1, mat, -1);
    check2 = HorizontalCheck(x1, y1, mat, 0);
    check3 = VeritcalCheck(x1, y1, mat, -1);
    check4 = VeritcalCheck(x1, y1, mat, 0);
    check5 = DiagonalCheck(x1, y1, mat, -1);
    check6 = DiagonalCheck(x1, y1, mat, 0);
    if (check == 1 || check3 == 1 || check5 == 1)
        Win_Event(-1, x1, y1, mat);
    if (check2 == 1 || check4 == 1 || check6 == 1)
        Win_Event(0, x1, y1, mat);
    Tie_Check(x1, y1, mat, player);
}
```

the problem im having is specifically with the lines where i assign check variables to the function DiagonalCheck that function looks like this:

```
int DiagonalCheck(int x1, int y1, int mat[][MAX], int sign) {
    int initialX = 0, initialY, i, j = initialX, CurrentX, Count;
    for (j; j < x1;) {
        Count = 0;
        for (CurrentX = j, initialY = 0; initialY <= y1 - 1; initialY++, CurrentX++) {
            if (mat[initialY][CurrentX] == sign)
                Count++;
            if (mat[initialY][CurrentX] != sign)
                Count = 0;
            if (Count == 4)
                return 1;
            printf("%d\n", Count);
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

for all of the other functions they work as intended and check things for different parameters but specifically with this function the input from both functions kind of merges.
i know solutions to this in other languages but never encouterd it in C before and would like some help in fixing the problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now the biggest problem in `DiagonalCheck` is the blatant ability to exit that function without returning a determinate result. In fact, there is only *one* possible determinate condition, and it is always `1` and highly conditional. If the outer loop runs to exhaustion you simply... exit, leaving the result, and its interpretations to the throws of *undefined behavior*.  Your compiler should be barking loudly at you about this, and if it isn't, you need to  turn up your warning levels and treat them ALL as errors.

Comment: Use `else` when the second condition is the opposite of the first condition.

Comment: Why do you have `j++` in the body of the loop instead of the `for()` header?

Comment: What makes you think the input is "merging"? How can you tell?

Comment: yhea i know i couldve put it up there but i didnt think it would matter too much.

Comment: basically the diagonal function counts the amount of times a certein value shows up diagonally without anything in between so i could tell it was merging because when i printed it both values were printing indtead of 1

Comment: how can i use an else statement on those functions?

Comment: `if (mat[initialY][CurrentX] == sign)
                Count++; else Count = 0;`

Comment: To fix the problem @WhozCraig pointed out, just add `return 0;` at the end of the function.

Comment: What exactly this function should do? Check diagonal values and if 4 consecutive diagonal values equals `sign` return `1` otherwise it returns `0`?

Comment: yes thats exactly it

Comment: As already mentioned just add `return 0;` at the end of the function. You may also need to check the value of `CurrentX` (not to allow to be bigger than the matrix size).

Comment: ive added the return 0; to the end of the function it didnt change the output.

Comment: what i mean by "end" is the after the outer loop ends

Comment: If you provide a [mre] we can check it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

i finally figured it out what i did was just have 2 signs be entered into the same function and then run the same code inside of the function for each sign and returning 0 at the end of the second outer loop.